# Android Media Player Next Song

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview in MainActivity from hehe i passing my listview position using this

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Linkview.class);

            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent);
```

And I have a Linkview class here i received my position using this

```
 final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  position = bundle.getInt("position");
```

And i have a linkArray list.

```
  link = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lin
```

My player play well and i can stop it.
But I have a next button

```
  next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                uri = Uri.parse(link[position+1]);

        }
    });
```

When I pressed my next button nothing is happened. I want that when I pressed the next button from my `array` next link will be play but nothing is play.
How i can solve this issue.

My hole code is here.

```
public class Linkview extends Activity {
    Button play, stop, next;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private String currentSongIndex;
    RowItem rowItem;
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    Uri uri;
    public String link[];
    int position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_linkview);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton1);
        link = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.link);

        // String itemString = MainActivity.link[position];

        final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        // String link = bundle.getString("link");
        // position = bundle.getInt("position");

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                if (position <= 2) {
                    uri = Uri.parse(link[position + 1]);
                }
            }
        });
        position = bundle.getInt("position");
        uri = Uri.parse(link[position]);

        // .parse("android.resource://com.prgguru.example/"
        // + R.raw.hosannatamil);");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }

            }
        });

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });

    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) example.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will work:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        uri = Uri.parse(link[position + 1]);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();              
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```